# scrap SharePoint folders?

Tags: sharepoint-server, script

I have an old SharePoint (not SharePoint Online) with multiple parent folders by US States and child folders with different Years. Each year has folders by Orders. I want to go check in each Order folder if it has a document named 'Order History'. Is there a way to bring result in an excel file with Year and Order number if it has the required document present?

In short, Instead of going into each order folder manually want a way to automatically pull data in rows like SQL does. Is it possible? Where does SharePoint stores all these documents data in the back end?

Comment: What does this mean?  I want to go check in each Order folder if it has a document named 'Order History'

Comment: Basically, I'm not touching any files from on-prem SharePoint. Just want to access database or backend storage and see if a folder has any file named 'order history' or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to access SQL table for such information. And it is not a recommended approach to directly access database. I assume all the folders are in one library, then it can be easily done with PnP PowerShell.

Here is the script:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$Files=Find-PnPFile -List <Library Name> -Match  "Order History.txt"
Foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    write-host $file.serverRelativeURL
}
```

If you have not installed PnP, please install the module with this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps).

Demo export in my end:
[image]